# CorePlot 1.5.1 pod install failed

Tags: ios, cocoapods, core-plot

I can install *AFNetworking* with the Podfile below,

```
platform :ios, '7.0'  
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

but failed to install **CorePlot**, here is my Podfile,

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform : ios, "8.0"

target "CorePlotTest" do

pod 'CorePlot', '~> 1.5.1'

end
```

Here is my error codes,

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your podfile. Remove the space between the colon (:) and "ios" on the platform line.

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents in the file are no problems, just open the *Podfile* in **vim** or **Xcode**, not other things like *TextEdit* !

We can use

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

to open and edit the file in Xcode.